# Umbraco 4 Content Macro

Tags: macros, umbraco

I have made a usercontrol which I use as a content macro in umbraco.  All works fine on the development server but when I have deployed it to the staging server, the macro doesn't work.

For some reason the macro is having it's contents deleted by the wysiwyg - on the development server the macro html looks like this:

```
<div umb_buttontext="Download the case study &gt;" umb_linkdocument="1581" umb_buttonimage="1585" umb_macroalias="DownloadButton" ismacro="true" onresizestart="return false;" umbversionid="573dbd37-24e3-4d67-80b6-84d915c38409" umbpageid="1215" title="This is rendered content from macro" class="umbMacroHolder">
<!-- startUmbMacro -->
  <p class="downloadButton"><a id="DownloadButton_1_lnkButton" style="padding-left: 77px;" href="http://www.fmg.co.uk/results/highways-agency/highways-agency-download/" class="button">Download the case study &gt;<span class="image" style="background-image: url('/media/38897/highwaysagency.png'); width: 57px; height: 69px;"> </span></a></p>
<!-- endUmbMacro -->
</div>
```

but on the staging server the part between the comments is deleted, even if I delete the macro and try to insert it from scratch:

```
<div umb_buttontext="Download the case study &gt;" umb_linkdocument="1581" umb_buttonimage="1585" umb_macroalias="DownloadButton" ismacro="true" onresizestart="return false;" umbversionid="573dbd37-24e3-4d67-80b6-84d915c38409" umbpageid="1215" title="This is rendered content from macro" class="umbMacroHolder">
<!-- startUmbMacro -->
<!-- endUmbMacro -->
</div>
```

I have also tried copying and pasting the macro directly into the html of the wysiwyg and this works until I save and then the bit inside the comments is removed again.

Does anyone know why this happens as I have tried searching for an answer but could not find anything.  Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, when I published the site, the dll didn't get updated properly and so the usercontrol for the macro was referencing something undefined or null causing the macro to break.

I think that whenever a macro is broken, it will clear the content in the wysiwyg area as described above.  Once I fixed the usercontrol, the macro worked properly again.  This also happened on a couple of other macros too but instead of trying to edit the page I fixed the usercontrol behind the macro and it seemed to solve those problems too.